# Is there a way to only copy text in a certain format, while ignoring the rest?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in a cell which mean different things in different formats. It is similar to the following: **146976 12323** *8448948 983893*. I need to only extract the data that is bolded (it is also red, if that matters), while ignoring the italicized data.

Originally I tried to use an If Statement, however that only works if the conditions are 100% met, and I tried using the text-to-columns feature to split the cell, however the format of the text isn't carried over to the new cell.

I will be running this in a macro that isn't supposed to require user action. Is there a way this is possible? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have skipped the intro for this site: “Code this for me” questions are generally frowned upon around here, however, we’d love to help you learn! If you could, please post any code you have already tried. For further information on posting a question, you might want to have a look at this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: VBA can access the formatting of a cell. If your `If` statement approach didn't work chances are that you didn't formulate the condition clearly enough. You haven't formulated it clearly here either, for that matter. Just what sort of format determines if the data is to be extracted?

Comment: @Dr.Trey My mistake, I didn't mean to come across as a 'code this for me guy'. I just didn't think it was necessary to copy and paste code that Excel generated when recording a macro. Nevertheless, I'll be sure to post code from now on! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Consider three cells:

A1: **BOLD**

A2: Regular

A3: *Italic*

With code:

```
Sub CheckFormat()
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A3")
    If cell.Font.Bold = True Then
        Debug.Print "Cell: " + cell.Address + " is bold"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Output: `Cell :$A$1 is bold`

Answer (score 0):

This shows bold characters in a cell (numbers or letters):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub extractBoldText()

    Dim i As Long, boldStart As Long, boldTotal As Long, cel As Range, sz As Long

    Set cel = Cells(1, 1)   'A1 contains "146976 12323 8448948 983893"; 12323 is bold
    sz = Len(cel)

    If sz > 0 Then
        While Not cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Bold And i < sz
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        boldStart = IIf(i = 0, 1, i)
        While cel.Characters(Start:=i, Length:=1).Font.Bold And i < sz
            i = i + 1
        Wend
        boldTotal = IIf(i = sz, i, i - boldStart)
    End If

    If boldTotal > 0 Then MsgBox Mid(cel, boldStart, boldTotal) 'Will output "12323"

End Sub
```